# Use an Arduino to control a 12v rgb strip

Tags: arduino, transistors, led-strip, rgb

I am wishing to use an Arduino UNO to control a 12v RGB LED strip. Can I use a transistor instead of a relay? The LED strip has 4 pins: `+` , `R`, `G` and `B`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. A N-Channel transistor of the right collector current capacity on the R, G & B pins can be used.

[image]

Comment: Thank you lots! Only one more question. I don't have any TIP31s. What else could I use?  Most of my transistors are BC-Somthings

Comment: @Jackpen7 depends on the current required. How many leds?

Comment: Three leds are needed

Comment: @Jackpen7 your led strip is only three leds, 1 segment long?

Comment: Correct, only 1 segment

Comment: Then you can use a simple 2n3904 or 2n2222 transistor.

Comment: You can also use BC547/8/9 or BC337, like the ones you probably have.